# How do I access/transfer/map attributes from my Azure AD token to my Cognito token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, access-token

I'm uncertain about how to transfer Azure Roles from the Azure Access Token to the AWS Cognito Access Token.

I have a Cognito User Pool (Authorization Code Flow) set up with Azure Federation Gateway.

When I access the Azure token URL, I receive a token similar to this:

```json
{
    "aud": "21718f33-3abc7",
    "roles": ["P360_SuperUser"]
}
```

However, when I access the Cognito token URL, the token generated by Cognito does not contain the roles from Azure.

I'm trying to figure out how to transfer the Azure Roles and other claims to the AWS Cognito access-token. I would like these roles to be included in the Cognito access token.

Comment: ' roles P360_SuperUser' - in where? what claim? can you share a sample Azure AD token, what value you want from it and then your Cognito token? Is this the access token or the ID token?

Comment: Sure If you see this payload data (hitting directly Azure /token endpoint), I am getting roles as P360_SuperUser.
 Now If configure the cognito and then hit the azure /token endpoint. I want that these roles should come to cognito access token.
 Azure Token: {
                    "aud": "21718f33-3abc7",
                    "roles": [
                         "P360_SuperUser"
                     ],
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like these roles to be included in the Cognito access token.

This is not possible for access tokens - it can only be done for ID tokens.

---

If the same data exists in the ID token, you can create a custom attribute for `roles` in your User Pool & then configure attribute mapping between the custom attribute in Amazon Cognito and the `roles` claim from Azure AD.

Generic guidance is available in [this](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-tokens-issued-by-idp) official Knowledge Center article, but I've expanded on the steps and tailored the answer to your specific scenario.

---

1. AWS Console > your User Pool > 'Sign-up Experience' > 'Custom Attributes' > 'Add custom attributes'
2. Set name to `roles`, leave everything else as default (type: string, mutable: yes**<sup>1</sup>**) & 'Save changes'. This now allows you to map `roles` over from Azure to `custom:roles`**<sup>2</sup>** in your Cognito ID token.

[image]

3. AWS Console > your User Pool > 'Sign-in Experience' > 'Federated identity provider sign-in' > your federated identity provider (Azure AD in this case) > 'Attribute mapping' > 'Edit'
4. Add a new entry, selecting `custom:roles` in the first 'User pool attribute' column and setting `roles` as the OpenID Connect attribute, which matches with what the Azure AD token has. This maps `roles` from the federated identity token to `custom:roles` in the Cognito ID token. Then, 'Save Changes'.

[image]

5. AWS Console > your User Pool > 'App integration' > 'App client list' > your app client > 'Attribute read and write permissions' > 'Edit' > tick the 'Read' and 'Write' checkboxes for `custom:roles (mutable)` to enable your app client to work with the custom attribute<sup>3</sup>. Repeat this for as many app clients as needed.

[image]

6. Use the `custom:roles` claim in the Cognito ID token to obtain the `P360_SuperUser` value<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> *As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html#cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping-requirements), all of the user pool custom attributes that you map from your IdP must be mutable.* This is because [immutable attributes can only be written to when you create a user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html?icmpid=docs_cognito_console_help_panel#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes) and since we're setting the value of the attribute *after* the user has already been created, we need it to be mutable.

<sup>2</sup> *As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html?icmpid=docs_cognito_console_help_panel#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes), custom attribute names are always prefixed “custom:” in Amazon Cognito requests. This can't be changed & is there to distinguish custom attributes from standard attributes.*

<sup>3</sup> *As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html#cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping-requirements), when a user signs in through an IdP, Amazon Cognito will need to update the mapped attribute with the latest value from the IdP on sign-in. By default, custom attributes are set to *not* be readable and to *not* be writable. Even if it's configured as mutable, Cognito still requires you to set the mapped user pool `custom:roles` attribute as readable & writable; otherwise, it can't update the attribute & will throw an error. This needs to be changed.*

*<sup>4</sup> `roles` is an array & may contain multiple values. As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html#cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping-requirements), if it contains multiple values, Cognito will flatten all of the (array) values into a single space-delimited string and URL form-encodes the values containing non-alphanumeric characters (excluding the ‘.’, ‘-’, ‘*’, and ‘_’ characters). You might need to decode & parse the individual values within your app.*

Comment: 'You need to make it to `azure.id-token`'

Comment: Is it possible to pass this 'roles' claim from cognito authoriser to API lambda?